# git clone works but push doesn't after replacing SSL certificate behind firewall

Tags: git, github

Cloning my repo works; pushing back to it doesn't.

**1st cloning did not work:**

```
git clone https://github.com/slimsnerdy/testy.git
Cloning into 'testy'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/slimsnerdy/testy.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in
certificate chain
```

**So I added to the `.gitconfig` file the following custom certificate:**

```
[http]
    sslCAInfo = U:/ca-bundle.crt
```

**Now cloning works:**

```
Cloning into 'testy'...
remote: Counting objects: 25, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
remote: Total 25 (delta 8), reused 6 (delta 1), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (25/25), done.
```

**Ok now pushing:**

```
new-item test.txt
git add *
git commit -m "push test"
git push
Username for 'https://github.com': slimsnerdy
Password for 'https://slimsnerdy@github.com':
remote: Anonymous access to slimsnerdy/testy.git denied.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/slimsnerdy/testy.git/'
```

When I try to push via a personal hotpot using my phone (circumventing the corporate firewall), it pushes fine.

Why is `clone` working with the custom certificate but not `push`?
I want to get around this without using ssh.

Answer (score 11):

Your company's firewall has installed a proxy which acts as [man in the middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). To that end, it creates certificates for the sites you visit, e.g. github.com. These certificates obviously have a different issuer (your company's internal CA) which will not be trusted by the git client by default. Turning off `sslVerify` forces the git client to accept any certificate from any issuer. This is potentially dangerous. Your original approach, to add your company's CA to the list of issuers trusted by the git client, is IMHO the better way to allow your git client to talk to github.com from behind your company's firewall.

So why doesn't this setup let you `push`? What the other posters overlooked so far, is that the error in this case is *not* an SSL error. Only your client sees your company's certificate. If that is solved, it is solved. Github does not see this certificate. So any further tweaking with SSL settings will not help.

I could reproduce your case in so far as I could first see the SSL self-signed certificate problem which disappeared when I added the proxy's certificate to `sslCAInfo`. The bad news: I could *not* reproduce the *authentication failed* error. A push to github just worked. The good news: pushing to github from a setup similar to your's is possible.

If it is not a SSL problem, then it can only be caused by the proxy. Because the proxy presents its own certificate to the client, it is able to decrypt the SSL traffic and do a deep inspection of the data exchanged. The proxy does have the power to disable certain commands, to restrict access to specific sites or to strip username/password from requests.

Please talk to the IT security folks in your company. They should be able clarify whether the proxy imposes access restrictions for github or for certain git commands.

**Update**

Routing git web traffic through Fiddler can be acomplished as follows (use git from the command line):

1. Run Fiddler
2. In git bash, cd to your working directory and add the options `-c http.sslVerify=false -c http.proxy=127.0.0.1:8888` to the git command.

Example:

```
$ git -c http.sslVerify=false -c http.proxy=127.0.0.1:8888 push
```

In Fiddler, you should now see something like:

```
2   200 HTTP    Tunnel to   github.com:443  0           git-remote-https:6512           
3   401 HTTPS   github.com  /xxx/xxxx.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack [...]      
4   200 HTTPS   github.com  /xxx/xxxx.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack [...]
```

Or, exported with "terse summary" (Ctrl/Shift/T):

```
CONNECT http://github.com:443
200 Connection Established ()

GET https://github.com/xxx/xxxx.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
401 Authorization Required (text/plain)

GET https://github.com/xxx/xxxx.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
200 OK (application/x-git-receive-pack-advertisement)
```

In the right pane of the Fiddler Web Debugger, you can further investigate the data exchanged. Especially for the last of the three request shown above, you should see something like this in the "Headers" tab:

```
GET /xxx/xxxx/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com
Authorization: Basic XyzzY1337qQ=
User-Agent: git/2.13.0.windows.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache
```

Thus you can prove that your client indeed sent authorization info. If not, I would be very interested in the results.

Comment: Agree - it's definitely not an SSL issue.  I _suspect_ (without much evidence) that the proxy is stripping Basic credentials for some stupid reason.  If that's true, it's going to be _very_ challenging to make this work correctly over HTTP(S).

Comment: This is EXACTLY it. The authentication details when asked (username/pass) are being stripped completely and this results in the "anonymous" error.

Comment: Any way Fiddler can come to the rescue?

Comment: Fiddler is a debugging proxy which sits between your client and the internet. Thus you would only see the communication between the client and your company's proxy. What you would need is a trace of the communication beween your company's proxy and the internet.

Comment: If you have a web server under your control (and outside your company), you could test the behavior of your company's proxy against your own server.

Comment: @AdrianW My logic was using Fiddler to send to the proxy (company) what it wants to authenticate.. as in replace the SSL before it hits the proxy with what is "desired" by the proxy.

Comment: @Snerd when the proxy denies the connection, you get `fatal: unable to access '....' The requested URL returned error: 403`. The message you get is `remote: Anonymous access .... denied`. This message is from the remote git, i.e. GitHub.

Comment: Do you need help on how to route git through fiddler?

Comment: @Edward Thomson one part of the evidence is the message from `remote` saying `Anonymous access denied`. A trace of the original request with Fiddler, as suggested by OP, would very likely show `Authorization Header is present` and thus complete the evidence.

Comment: @AdrianW yes help with routing Git through Fiddler would help.

Comment: @Snerd I updated the answer to include an example on how to route git's web I/O through Fiddler. Fiddler uses its own man-in-the-middle certificate. To allow git to accept it, I chose to add `-c  http.sslVerify=false` on the command line. So, it will be accepted for this request only and it is not necessary to change the configuration permanently.

Comment: @Snerd FYI: Updating git for windows (to 2.17.x) offers an option to chose an HTTPS transport backend. Choices: _Use the OpenSSL library_  and _Use the native Windows Secure Channel library_. Description for the latter: _Server certificates will be validated using Windows Certificate Stores. This option also allows you to use your company's internal Root CA certificates distributed e.g. via Active Directory Domain Services._ I.e. no longer necessary to tweak ca-bundle.crt.

Comment: @AdrianW I tried using the Windows library during another reinstall.. it didn't work, unless I missed something? But it DOES make sense.

Comment: Just a finding I wanted to share.

Answer (score 4):

I am sure this could help you.

`git config --global http.sslVerify false`

As you may guess, this command changes ssl setting to disable ssl verification.

> Warning: This method is insecure.

If you want it back, you can enable anytime.

`git config --unset http.sslVerify`

Comment: This was one of the 1st things tried and not "secure." But ya this didn't solve `push`.

Comment: @Snerd, doesn't it work? If so, please let me see the error message.

Answer (score 4):

For testing disable temporally SSL for your repository with:

```
git config http.sslVerify false
```

Then also check that your system clock is in sync since this can influence how SSL verification works, you may get something like:

```
[SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. 
Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed])
```

Try to use [ntp](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/use.html)/[chrony](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/) to synchronize your system clock.

Then to get the certificate you could use:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect github.com:443 < /dev/null
```

Get everything within `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and  `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` and create a `cert.pem`

Then use that file as you are trying in `http.sslCAInfo`:

```
git config http.sslCAInfo /path/to/cert.pem
```

Once done try enabling back the `http.sslVerify`:

```
git config --unset http.sslVerify
```